# Rust: fail to parse integer to string, ParseIntError

Tags: string, rust, integer

I just started to experiment with Rust, so I've implemented modified version from Book's "Guessing game". Every first time I'm trying to enter the number, program fails to parse integer from string:

```
Guess the number!
Input your guess:
50
You guessed 50
 (4 bytes)!
thread 'main' panicked at 'Wrong number format!: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', src\libcore\result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\release\experiment.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

Code applied below.

I already tried other integer types.

```
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!\nInput your guess:");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    let secnum = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1,101);

    'br: loop { 
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess) {
            Ok(okay) => {
                println!("You guessed {} ({} bytes)!", guess, okay);

                let intguess = guess.parse::<u8>()
                    .expect("Wrong number format!");

                match secnum.cmp(&intguess) {
                    std::cmp::Ordering::Less => {
                        println!("Your guess is smaller!");
                    }
                    std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => {
                        println!("Your guess is bigger!");
                    }
                    std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => {
                        println!("You guessed right!");
                        break 'br;
                    } 
                }
            }
            Err(erro) => {
                println!("Failed to read the line: {}!", erro);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of `read_line` includes the `'\n'` character, which is causing the parse error.

Comment: You can just call `string.clear()` to reuse the same string. In this kind of IO code, there is really very little impact to allocating a new `String` each time though.

Comment: Does fs:: read_string also do the same, like includes the \n character ? I was reading from this file https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1/input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string output from `read_line` includes a trailing newline character, so you will need to strip that out in order to parse the number. You can do that with `trim_end` (or just `trim` to handle leading whitespace too):

```
let guess: u8 = guess
    .trim_end()
    .parse()
    .expect("Wrong number format!");
```